# 56 Passat 2.0 Tdi dull humming noise somewhere behind driver seat?

Tags: noise

0 Tdi Passat and it has suddenly started humming and sounds like it's behind me in the back some where?? The noise happens sometimes and other times it's not there. It doesn't change whether I'm stationary or moving and doesn't change with revving the engine. There's no difference in drive and performance but it's annoying when it happens! Any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

The sound you are hearing is most likely the fuel pump. You can test this in the morning. Before you start the engine, turn the key on and see if you hear the noise. It should probably be about 4-5 seconds in length, then it will quit. This is the fuel pump ensuring the system has enough pressure to run correctly when the engine starts. Fuel will drain back out of the system overnight (in most cases). If this is what is happening, it is usually completely normal. And it affects gas (petrol) or diesel engines alike in modern fuel injected cars (both have electric fuel pumps).

Comment: It does the noise randomly and when it does it it can last minutes rather than seconds. Didn't do the noise this morning with the ignition